# Security Audit (CRUD) - Microsoft Access

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access, vba, audit

My client has been using Microsoft Access 2010 for quite a while and they received some Security Audit Requirements. They are using a Linked Tables approach connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express.

The requirements states that all actions against the data must be logged. (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AND SELECT statements)

For the INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements I could create a trigger which would log the changes.

The issue is around the audit of SELECT statements. If the data was read-only, I could have used a Stored Procedure which would have logged the query. But executing a Stored Proc makes a Recordset not updatable.

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this challenge?

I'm open to a lot of strategies... (Connecting Access to SQL through a web service, anything...)

It's important to note that my client does not have $30k to spend on an Enterprise edition of SQL Sever as they are a small-business with less than 10 employees.

Comment: Yes/No... I would need to have really good arguments to switch to a different RDBMS. One thing for sure is that I'm locked into Microsoft Access... Before I got on board they spent many many hours of development in it.

Comment: The tracking of select commands seems lame. An access form bound to a table allows use of SQL profiler – even the express edition. The problem is now you loaded 500 records and then the user hits ctrl-f to find a row. Such ctrl-f commands don’t generate or cause any SQL to be sent to the server. Not different then download a web page and user hits ctrl-f. Tracking SELECT tells you VERY little about what the user actually looked at UNLESS ALL your forms are limited to one record via a “where” clause upon open. If all forms are loaded to one record, then such select statements could logged.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT statements are part of the [database-level audit action groups in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280663.aspx). (Search that page for "database-level audit actions".) But that level of auditing requires SQL Server Enterprise edition.

Theoretically, you can limit all access to use only stored procedures regardless of whether the data is read-only. Write the stored procedure to write auditing information to the log first, then do whatever else needs to be done--SELECT, INSERT, etc.

Practically, you *might* not be able to do that. It depends on the applications that hit your database. Limiting all access to use only stored procedures can break applications that expect other things. (How would a Ruby on Rails application respond if you switched to just stored procedures?)

A bulletproof audit system that makes your database unusable isn't very good; it's simpler and cheaper to just shut down the database server altogether.

Comment: The major issue is that I'm using Microsoft Access. If I was developing a .NET Web App, I would Trust the Web Application and make it responsible to create the audit records.

Comment: Microsoft Access shouldn't be an issue. Auditing and permissions should be in the back-end dbms (SQL Server), not in application code. DBAs (and often others) can usually go right around application code.

Comment: I agree with you... I doubt I can implement such audit controls in Access... As far as I know, a Linked Tables to a SP (which would create the audit trail) makes the table Read-Only in Access.

I believe my only option is to create various C/R/U/D stored procedures and call them through VBA.

What I meant with the .NET Web App is that: as I would fully trust the Web App, I could rely on it to call the SP to get the data and call regular INS/UPD/DEL which would have a trigger recording the change. (Or simply make the Web App record the audit trail as I can fully trust the app) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade to a SQL Server edition that supports SQL Server profiler.
The other option is to get other tools to audit like sql audit for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on JET showplan. This would log all queries used by Access.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/?siu-container

As I pointed out in comments you really fooling the audit requirements UNLESS each form is opened using a where clause that limits the viewing of data in that form to the ONE record. If you don’t do this, then a form opened to a linked table could have 1000’s of records, and user(s) hitting ctrl-f to find and jump to one record means the SELECT statement tells you ZERO about what the user actually looked at. So while you can turn on show plan, the audit concept would not tell you anything about what the user actually looked at unless application design changes are made to restrict forms to one record. And to be fair, 99% of my applications in fact do open and restrict the main editing form to the one record via a where clause.

So while you can technology wise log all SELECT commands as per above, it not really in the sprit of such a log since such a log would not be of any use to determine what actual records the user looked at.